# creating a table with codeignituer db forge. automate code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dbforge

Is there a way to take an existing mysql create table String, and turn it into a db_forge array/script suitable for the create_table() method?, ie basically reverse the dbforge process.  It is just quicker to make tables in something like Sequel pro, then copy the sql code to the model.

I already have the mysql code, but i was thinking of using the dbforge to allow different databases to be used.

Do people use the dbforge? or just write the SQL creation code manually?

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want to create tables through codeigniter then use migrations class it can solve your problem. you can create, update and delete table with migrations.

[CI Migration class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html)

Comment: sorry that isn't answering the question.

Comment: migration is also using db forge and its is right way to create tables with migrations

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated process to do what you ask. You have to convert it manually.

I have found that once I became familiar with the dbforge syntax, I can create tables just as quickly, if not quicker, than using Sequel Pro or another SQL GUI.